# How to make android app that reads pdf books easily

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, mobile-application, pdf-reader

I am trying to build an android application that reads PDF books .
I am developing using android studio
 the books will be within the app files ,, so the app is not for reading other PDF books on the phone.
also i will add a feature to it ,,so that when i click on a paragraph  ,a sound file will be played.

I hope you can help me out and guide me at least with the main steps to do that.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apache PDFBox is an API to read pdf documents.

Start with this tutorial-https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/getting-started.html

Comment: i opened the link but it show this massage: This content is under construction.

Comment: May be routine maintenance was under process then, try again.